# Should I extend my Interface or the concrete implementation of my class?

Tags: oop

Let's say I've an `ArticleInterface` and a `VoteableInterface`.

When declaring my `ArticleInterface` should I extend the new interface with the `VoteableInterface` or I should do it inside the concrete implementation of the `ArticleInterface`?

### Option 1.

```
interface ArticleInterface extends VoteableInterface {}
```

### Option 2.

```
interface ArticleInterface {}

class Article implements ArticleInterface, VoteableInterface {}
```

**Which one is the better and why?**

Answer (score 3):

The answer depends on whether, conceptually, `ArticleInterface` is a `VoteableInterface` or not - if it is then extending is appropriate (Option 1), but if they are distinct then implement them both separately (Option 2).

Comment: MMmm I got your point, but, well the purpose of the VoteableInterface is to make an Article Voteable by implementing the appropriate method therefore, it is a Voteable object, so..

Comment: It sounds like they represent separate capabilities - if VoteableInterface just contains a vote() method for example, and has nothing to do with Articles specifically, then you should probably keep them separate.